# jQuery and default struts 2 submit buttons in one form

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, double-submit-problem

I have a problem with submitting form, which contains normal and jQuery `submit` button.

This is code snippet of my JSP:

```
<sj:head loadAtOnce="true"/>

<s:form id="createModReadProjectForm" action="createProject" cssClass="internalForm" autocomplete="off">
    <s:token/>

    <s:textfield name="collName" cssClass="textField internal" cssErrorClass="textFieldError internal" />
    <div id="assignCollaborators">

    </div>

    <s:url action="assignCollabolator" id="assignCollaboratorUrl"/>
    <sj:submit key="labels.button.addColl" targets="assignCollaborators" 
            id="assignCollButton" formIds="createModReadProjectForm" cssClass="button small"
            href="%{assignCollaboratorUrl}"/>

    <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

`jQuery submit` button only adds typed into textfield user name to `ArrayList` and list all saved users in `div` with `id="assignCollaborators"` and this works fine.

Rendered `jQuery submit` :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     var options_assignCollButton = {};
     options_assignCollButton.jqueryaction = "button";
     options_assignCollButton.id = "assignCollButton";
     options_assignCollButton.name = "labels.button.addColl";
     options_assignCollButton.targets = "assignCollaborators";
     options_assignCollButton.href = "/CloudUML/assignCollabolator.action";
     options_assignCollButton.formids = "createModReadProjectForm";

     jQuery.struts2_jquery.bind(jQuery('#assignCollButton'),options_assignCollButton);
});
```

Now when I want to submit form, using last submit button, nothing happens. No Java or JavaScript errors. What can cause such strange behavior? Why jQuery `submit` works fine, when normal Struts2 `s:submit` not?

I assure that all needed actions and property fields are defined.

EDIT:

When I've created simple submit JavaScript`function and assign its to`onclick` event to the last submit, it works properly.

```
function submitFunc() {
        document.forms['createModReadProjectForm'].submit();
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you click on second (default) submit w/o clicking on jQuery plugin submit? Does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Only when I complete remove jQuery submit it works. Even if I click or not on the jQuery submit, struts submit doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of struts2-jquery-plugin?

Comment: struts2-jquery-plugin ver. 3.6.1.

Comment: Seems like a bug: http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=931.

Comment: That's true. An information that it works in ver. 3.3.3 is also correct. Can you please write its as an answer to may question, thanks to that I will be able to accept its?

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in struts2-jquery-plugin: http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=931.

It should work with version 3.3.3 of that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is the e.PreventDefault() to prevent a normal submit on press enter inside of an form textfield.

See:
http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/struts2/jquery.struts2.js#947

What about using an normal Link instead of an button?