# sj:submit and s:submit on the same form

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I've got an s:form with sj:submit and s:submit inside, sj:submit works properly but s:submit buttons doesn't works. Nothing happens when I click on s:submit buttons.

I tried to use sj:submit button outside the form and linking that to s:form with formIds parameter.

Comment: Nevermind, it works perfectly without extra buttons.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18944973/1700321.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using:

```
<s:submit onClick="overrideSubmit('this_action')"/>
```

and

```
function overrideSubmit(actionName) {
        document.forms['configurationForm'].action = actionName + '.action';
        document.forms['configurationForm'].submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is the e.PreventDefault() to prevent a normal submit on press enter inside of an form textfield.

See:
http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/struts2/jquery.struts2.js#947

What about using an normal Link instead of an button?

Comment: I cannot use a link because I need to send data via POST, but thanks, I didn't spotted that prevent default!

Comment: With <sj:a ... /> tag you can also send forms with POST. This is the default behavior.